# Clarification of topological space definition in terms of neighborhoods

Tags: general-topology, continuity, uniform-continuity

> Let $X$ be a set. We allow $X$ to be empty. Let $N$ be a function assigning to each $x$ in $X$ a non-empty collection $N(x)$ of subsets of $X$. The elements of $N(x)$ will be called neighbourhoods of $x$ with respect to $N$ (or, simply, neighbourhoods of $x$).

An empty set has no subsets. If $X$ is empty (which the definition says is permissible), and $N$ must be a function assigning to each element $x$ in $X$ a **non-empty collection** of subsets of $X$, then...what's going on here?

An empty set can have a non-empty collection of subsets? Please elaborate. I'm trying to understand the concept of continuity and uniform continuity in a topological sense and misunderstanding of this definition is kind of in the way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another way of looking at what others have said. A function $f:X \to Y$ should consist of a triple $(X,Y,G_f)$ where $G_f$ is a "functional" subset of $X \times Y$, in the sense that for each $x \in X$ there is a unique $y$ in $Y$ such that $(x,y) \in G_f$. So if $X$ is empty, there is a unique function $X \to Y$. In categorical terms, the empty set is **initial** in the category of sets and function, just as the trivial group is initial in the category of groups and morphisms.

Answer (score 2):

This is vacuous when $X$ is empty.  It is easy to assign a non-empty subset $N(x)\subseteq X$ to each element $x\in X$ when there are no elements in the set $X$ to begin with!

After all... can you point out an element $x$ which violates the property?

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is empty, all predicates of the form $\forall x\in X,\  P(x)$ are true. In particular, yes, for all $x\in\emptyset$, the property of $N(x)$ is verified.

Answer (score 1):

You are confused on two counts, and the other answers address only one of them.

First, as the others have said, even in a world with no fire-breathing dragons, it's easy to assign a fire-breathing dragon to each element of the empty set, because there are no elements of the empty set.

But second, as the others have *not* said, in this case there *are* fire-breathing dragons.  That is, there *is* a non-empty collection of subsets of the empty set.  Namely, the empty set has one subset, namely $\emptyset$.  There are, therefore, two *collections* of subsets of the empty set.  There's the empty collection, with no elements at all, and the complete collection that includes $\emptyset$, namely $\lbrace \emptyset\rbrace$.  Of these, one is nonempty (namely the second one).  So there you have a nonempty collection of subsets of the empty set.